# trouble implementing SEO correctly in next.js app using next-seo

Tags: next.js

I am using next-seo to implement seo in my next.js app. This app uses feather.js in the backend api.

I have implemented a default seo config in _app.js file as per the instruction. I need to override this in the users' dashboard with user info, but this info comes from the feathers.js backend api. so it's fetched asynchronously.
I fetched the info in ComponentDidMount.
What baffles me is that much as the overrides are reflected when I go to the users dashboard, when I view page source on the page in the dashboard, the override is not reflected. the metatags and title in that html remain the same as they were in pages like the landing page which never overrode the seo.

what should I do to fix this?

[my code snippets](https://gist.github.com/jermsam/673380b2cf8451d88362c9c1c473e3a1?fbclid=IwAR2uyDLj_SV2Cy6VXg2YDvp9fwRGN_3yuYkycb2Mx5aBIGO2tKkbAxxShVE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big up to Erik Condie. He gave valuable information on how to avoid this error in this issue.
https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo/issues/58